# Rigid body for a single point?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Is it possible to make rigid body of a single point? I want to make scene of hundreds very small objects and I don't want calculate rotation and any other unnecessary features. Can I make object acting like material point (like in school physics problems)? If it's impossible, how can I set particles to interact with scene objects but not each other?

Comment: particles by default cannot react with each other and will only react to objects with collision modifier. So i wonder...did you ever try something out with particles at all?

Comment: The question @Chris is asking is legit... it doesn't seem like you have tried particles because the answer to your question is quite simple: just use particles and enable collision on the other scene objects.

Comment: I tried, but I can't reach the same effect using particles. Actually I'm trying to use fluid flow force field to make particles or very small rigid bodies act like dust billowing from a fast-moving object. It works with tiny ico spheres but if I try the same thing with particles it doesn't work. They just stuck on floor and not moving anymore. I check friction of floor and it's zero. So, if you know how to replicate same effect using particle system let me know.